# How can I put fields_for cousin objects in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I'm not sure cousin objects is an actual term, but going with the usual parent/child relations, this was the best description I could come up with.

In my app I have:

```
class KeyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :phone_numbers, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :email_addresses, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :sale_contacts, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :sales_opportunities, :through => :sale_contacts
end
```

From the Key_Contact I also build up SaleContacts (so the same contact can participate across multiple sales opportunities):

```
class SaleContact < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :key_contact
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity
end
```

*Edit: Phone_Number model for clarity:

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :number, :key_contact_id, presence: true
 belongs_to :key_contact
end
```

In the app I'm using Bootstrap 3 Modals to host the form_for a sale_contact, load it into the page via AJAX and refresh a few partials. All of this works well, and in the newly rendered table there's a link to add either `phone_numbers` or `email_addresses` to the SaleContact (obviously it actually adds these objects to the KeyContact).

What I want to do is add fields_for `:phone_numbers` and `:email_addresses` to the SaleContact form. I've tried declaring the relationships (that a SaleContact `has_many :phone_numbers, :through => :key_contacts`) but this doesn't work as the key_contact has not been set for the sale_contact before the modal submits (the key_contact already exists, but the sale_contact has not yet saved the fact that the relationship is with that specific key_contact).

Is there an easy way to do this in rails? Or am I massively over-complicating things?

Comment: I think you should be able to use nested attributes to solve the problem

Comment: I tried that when declaring `SaleContact has_many :phone_numbers, :through => :key_contacts` and `SaleContact accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers` but the form would not load - because the key_contact relationship with the sale_contact had not yet been generated.

Comment: then you build one from the controller!

Comment: Thanks SunnyK - I'm just trying to get that working now - I've got the edit working (via a second modal) and just need to solve how to do this with the create action.

Comment: cool. If you need some code examples, I can provide you with some

Comment: I think I'm good now - I've got this working except for a 422 unprocessable entity error, which apparently comes from not putting :inverse_of relations in my model. I also need to change my error handling as I'm now loading the modals remotely, so the jquery needs touching up. Cheers for the help.